# Using AngularJS angular-store with Safari and incognito mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

I'm using angular-store to store some information during the user's session in my AngularJS application (version 1.4).

The code is very simple:

```
  service('Session', ["store", function(store){
      this.create = function(userId, userEmail, userToken, userRole, userFullName, userSurname, userBackground) {
          store.set("userId", userId);
          store.set("userEmail", userEmail);
          store.set("userToken", userToken);
          store.set("userRole", userRole);
          store.set("userFullName", userFullName);
          store.set("userSurname", userSurname);
          store.set("userBackground", userBackground);
      };

      this.destroy = function() {
          store.remove("userId");
          store.remove("userEmail");
          store.remove("userToken");
          store.remove("userRole");
          store.remove("userFullName");
          store.remove("userSurname");
          store.remove("userBackground");
      };
  }]).
```

It works fine in every browser but in Safari with incognito mode where it throws this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cookiesProvider <- $cookies <- cookieStorage <- localStorage <- store
```

There is a way I can solve this error?